# HTML & CSS: create a checkbox without using 'checkbox'

Tags: html, css, checkbox, inline

here's the code (and, yes, i'm using a basic reset.css):

```
.checkbox { border: 1px solid black; width: 10px; height: 10px; }

<ul>
    <li>
        <p><div class="checkbox"></div>I will!</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p><div class="checkbox"></div>I won't!</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

you can see what i'm trying to do.  essentially create a checkbox.  the reason i'm NOT using a checkbox tag is because i have to export this thing to PDF so that it can be printed and hamfisted bogots can drag their X mark through the box.  if i use the checkbox tag, it's too small.  if i use and image, PDF doesn't line up right.

so.  i need the CSS box to line up as expected.  what am i missing?  i've tried changing the div to `display: inline;` but it freakin' disappears!  `inline-block` useless.

i tried like mad to search this one out, but to no avail, so if this showed up somewhere else, apologies.

WR!

Comment: `display: inline-block;` seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xEtEK/2/ in Chrome/Mac. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.checkbox { 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    width: .65em; 
    height: .65em; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZeaLM/

Comment: You shouldn't be using `<p>` inside of a `<div>`, as that might cause unexpected results in different browsers (the code is invalid as `<p>` is not permitted to contain any block-level elements).

Comment: Since when is using a `<p>` inside a `<div>` a bad thing?  Also, I am not using a `<p>` inside a `<div>` and finally I was just modifying the CSS portion of his original code.

Comment: It's the other way around; `<div>` inside `<p>` is invalid html.

Comment: thanks.  combined with @Inerdia's comment, i got it working.  thanks.  i often forget to use good ol' `&nbsp` instead of empty space.

Comment: @jessegavin yes, I meant it the other way around, sorry about that :P

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` is the `display` you need for this.

Comment: Hopefully WhiteRau will explain *why* it didn't work, since it's what I've always used for this kind of situation (inline box of defined width/height) and it's always worked for me.

Comment: And works in this case (see my comment on the question) – so I'm guessing the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Truth there have been many times when I make unorderlist navigation I have to use inline-block. Very useful.

Comment: I know how and when to use `inline-block`, OP stated it didn't work for him that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser might be persnickety about empty elements. Try adding a `&nbsp;` into the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` is not allowed inside of `<p>` elements (which doesn't allow any block-level elements inside of it).

**[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/MNVfa/)**

In this example, I've used `display: inline-block;` and changed the `<p>` element into a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do it, one of which is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/f5D6M/)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure - did you put the .checkbox selector inside a `<style>` tag in the actual HTML?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .checkbox { border: 1px solid black; width: 10px; height: 10px; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Get rid of the `<p>` elements

2) Add `float: left` to your `.checkbox` style

3) Add `&nbsp;` after the `div` or a `padding: right` to the `div` block to make it look better

4) Add `li { list-style-type: none; }` in your style block

5) Play around with `vertical-align` in your `.checkbox` style until you're happy